# How do we know if data was successfully written in Firebase local datastore?

Tags: android, ios, firebase

I just discovered that write completion blocks do not run  until the writes have not been persisted to firebase server. Is there any way to listen to successful local data writes in firebase?

Comment: How would you intend to react to a local write being finished?  I think you can expect that all subsequent reads from the database will show the new data without having to worry about where exactly that data came from (memory or disk).

Answer (score 0):

As the [offical doc](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-completion-callback) for writting data to Firebase says, yes you can add a `Completion Listener`. Both `setValue()` and `updateChildren()` methods take an optional `Completion Listener` if needed, that is called when the write has been committed to the database.

So to achieve this, please use the following code:

```
yourRef.setValue("Writing Data!", new Firebase.CompletionListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(FirebaseError firebaseError, Firebase firebase) {
        if (firebaseError != null) {
            System.out.println("Data couldn't be saved! " + firebaseError.getMessage());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Data was saved successfully!");
        }
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The question is asking if it's possible to know when the write completes *locally*, whereas completion listeners trigger when the data has been synchronized *remotely*.  I presume the asker has persistence enabled in this case.

Comment: Thanks @DougStevenson for your explication.